# Is a 'passive' knurling ever desired?

Tags: barbell, equipment

When discussing barbell knurling, it is usually either aggressive or pretty passive (i.e. soft). When purchasing, the aggression and sharpness of the knurling is advertised. It lets you hold more. There's a line between a good sharp knurl and something that shreds your hand.

However, is there ever a scenario where using a passive or soft knurling is desired? In powerlifting it seems like you would *always* want a more aggressive knurl... but I'm not sure about universally.

Comment: Garage Gym Reviews has a nice video on knurling types https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rFSsUx_KDI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You have the space and money for two barbells.

You’ve pointed out the drawback of aggressive knurling: it tears your hands to shreds, and if you drag your shins when you deadlift, it rips them up or tears your socks. Using an aggressive knurl day in and day out may not be sustainable for these reasons. The last thing you want is to rip your calluses off during your last week of meet prep because you did all your heavy doubles and triples with a maximally aggressive knurl.

However, if you have the budget and a place to keep them (or your gym just has lots of different barbells), it may be worth keeping a “training barbell” and a “competition barbell” on hand. Use your training barbell with a more passive knurl for most of your daily work, and break out the aggressive “competition” barbell for your weekly singles or your test days.

Comment: *Two* barbells? In *this* economy?

Comment: @C.Lange Who needs a house when you have a shed out back with a squat rack and a bench to sleep on?

Comment: Ahaha, exactly. In seriousness though, I've only ever had pretty passive commercial gym bars so I hadn't thought about training with *only* max knurling. Looking now to buy something for home so I'll keep this in mind. I've got the space at least!

Comment: @C.Lange I’ve trained with a rogue deadlift bar before and it is realllllly rough on your hands, and I don’t think it’s the most aggressive knurl they make.

Answer (score 3):

When I was training powerlifting, my general preference was to always have a barbell with softer knurling, mostly to keep my hands healthy and because I didn't feel like it was necessary. Those "softer" barbells are also what you encounter at most gyms, in my experience, so I felt it was better to get used to lifting with one most of the time.

I only preferred a barbell with a more aggressive knurling when trying my limits, i.e. 1-3 RM, and when I needed the increased grip, and even then I only used it for deadlift. For squat and bench press I never felt the need for an aggressive knurling and the increased grip.

(Disclaimer: I wasn't a competition lifter but did train actively.)

Comment: I'd even say that is _undesireable_ to have aggresive knurling on a squat bar... all that knurling scratching the back / shoulders!